# Difference between android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item and android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item

Tags: java, android, spinner, android-arrayadapter

Here's a sample code of using spinner in android :

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.gender_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I have understood that we need to specify a layout for the datarows in the adapter

But why again using `setDropDownViewResource()` method. I mean what does this function do and also tell me how it is different from the constructor of the `ArrayAdapter`.

I have gone through the documentation, but didn't understand completely.

Answer (score 26):

Here's is the difference - See below images

### simple_spinner_item

[image: Simple_Spinner]

If you're using your spinner with `spinner.setAdapter(adapter);` directly in your code, your spinner will looks like above image.

But, if you're using `adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);` in your code, it'll show your spinner like below image where the spinner items will shown with radio buttons.

### simple_spinner_dropdown_item

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Normally the difference between android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item and android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item is

Simple spinner Dropdown view

[image: Simple spinner dropdown view]

Simple spinner view

[image: simple spinner view]

Answer (score 3):

The difference is as below:

1. simple_spinner_item is the layout of each drop-down item on the spinner list.
2. And inorder to house these x number of drop-down items, the layout required is
   simple_spinner_dropdown_item

Answer (score 1):

use adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice);

1. select_dialog_singlechoice  -- to show radio button
2. select_dialog_multichoice   --- multiple select
3. simple_spinner_dropdown_item  --- without radio button

just change this setDropDownViewResource line from above choice.