# Android static/dynamic spinner lists display differently

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

I am developing an Android application that uses two Spinner components. The first has its items assigned using XML at compile-time, the second has its items assigned during runtime. The list of the first Spinner is displayed using radio buttons and rows with plenty of padding. The second is displayed using only text, with minimal padding. I have tested this using Android API versions 7 and 9.

Why are they displayed differently and how do I prevent it?

**Edit** solution here: [Difference between android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item and android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10764918/difference-between-android-r-layout-simple-spinner-dropdown-item-and-android-r-l)

Turns out I was using two different layouts, because ArrayAdapter defaults to a different layout than when initialized in XML. I solved it by adding this line:
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

Comment: What do you mean they are displayed differently? Could you post some code so that we can figure out what is wrong?

Comment: You are using two different layouts for each spinner list, that is why you are getting different views at runtime and compile time.

Comment: Your comments helped me find the answer. Thanks!