# Difference between setAdapter() and setDropDownViewResource() on Spinner

Tags: android, spinner, android-view, android-adapter, android-resources

I looked at this question [Difference between android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item and android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10764918/difference-between-android-r-layout-simple-spinner-dropdown-item-and-android-r-l), but couldn't find an answer to my question.

I can see that there is a difference between simple_spinner_item and simple_spinner_dropdown_item. But why do I need to set them both? Which part of Spinner layout is controlled by layout set in `setAdapter() (simple_spinner_item )` and which one by layout set in `setDropDownViewResource() (simple_spinner_dropdown_item)`?

Right now I can't see why I can't do the opposite: use simple_spinner_item with `setDropDownViewResource()` and `simple_spinner_dropdown_item` with `setAdapter()`?

Answer (score 2):

I see the confusion. To rephrase: "Why do I even provide `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item` to the adapter's constructor? How is it used?"

The layout resource, that is provided to the adapter's constructor [is used](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/AbsSpinner.java#L194) to measure spinner row item's view. From `AbsSpinner#onMeasure()` `mAdapter.getView()` is called, which eventually [uses](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java#L371) `mResource` (the resource id, that was passed in to the adapter from constructor) to inflate the view.

On the other hand, the `mDropDownResource` [is used](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/Spinner.java#L971) to inflate each row of `Spinner`.

Note, that if you do not provide `mDropDownResource` explicitly, it defaults to the `mResource` that was provided in the constructor of adapter.

```
public ArrayAdapter(@NonNull Context context, @LayoutRes int resource,
        @IdRes int textViewResourceId, @NonNull List<T> objects) {
    ...
    mResource = mDropDownResource = resource;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the *simple_spinner_item* in *setAdapter*(), it used to show each row of item in the spinner. 
For the *simple_spinner_dropdown_item*, it used to show all rows of items when the user click the dropdown icon in the spinner. 
If you want to see the difference between both of them, you can try the steps below:

- create a customized resource layout for both *simple_spinner_item* and *simple_spinner_dropdown_item*
- create a **TextView** in both layouts
- change the **font colour** of the **TextView**

From that, you will see the difference.. thanks