# Why the layout file for an ArrayAdapter has to be set twice?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm creating an `ArrayAdapter` for a `Spinner` view.

Here's my (working) code:

```
val spinnerAdaptor = ArrayAdapter<String>(this@PlayerDetails, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, users)
spinnerAdaptor.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
choose_user?.adapter = spinnerAdaptor
choose_user.onItemSelectedListener = this@PlayerDetails
```

When I initialise my `spinnerAdaptor` I set the layout file for the dropdown in the 2nd parameter. Why is `setDropDownViewResource()` needed? (it doesn't work when I omit this line).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45128935/difference-between-setadapter-and-setdropdownviewresource-on-spinner

Answer (score 0):

- Main List item

  - Dropdown List item
  - Dropdown List item
- Main List item
- Main List item

First layout that you set in the constructor is your main list item layout, the 2nd layout is the dropdown item layout. You may want to set them differently.